Getting this error client side: oracle.forms.webutil.file.FileFunctions bean not found. WEBUTIL_FILE.FILE_SELECTION_DIALOG_INT will not work
I've started getting this error, oracle.forms.webutil.file.FileFunctions bean not found. WEBUTIL_FILE.FILE_SELECTION_DIALOG_INT will not work (came out of nowhere a few weeks ago) when trying to use a documents loading functionality in our client's Oracle Forms webapp (12.2.1.4). It's working fine for every other user in the organization, so it has to be something with the configuration in my machine.
I have Java JRE 1.8.0_201 and 1.8.0_121 coexisting in my PC, this is standard in this organization.
The only support I have got from the admins is to check for this folder and files
C:\Users\<myuser>\webutil\syslib 
d2kwut60.dll
ffisamp.dll
jacob.dll
JNIsharedstubs.dll
win32\d2kwut60.dll
win32\jacob-1.18-M2-x861.dll
win32\JNIsharedstubs.dll

I was missing it but after copying the files from another user it's still not working.
Googling the error hasn't been of any help, most issues seem to be related to the server side. Any ideas what could I be missing?

In the future, please alway include complete version numbers when posting.  "12c" is not a version number and could be represented by as many as 5 possible full version numbers.  Because each version offers new features, enhancements, and bug fixes, knowing the exact version can be important.
In the user's home directory you should find a webutil..properties file.  Delete it.  This will force the re-downloading of the needed libaries.  It is possible that your attempt to copy or something went wrong with the initial attempt to download these files went wrong.

Thank you, Michael. I have edited the original post to add the version number of the applet. I did find those files in my C:/users//, have deleted them, but nothing changed. They didn't re-donwload on the next login into the webapp, not even after a restart of the system. Am I missing something?

If webutil libraries are not being downloaded and/or error messages suggesting various WebUtil objects cannot be found, this often means that the configuration is not correct.  Do the following: recompile with the compile_all=yes flag then ensure you run with the proper config.  You can use the provided example.  In your URL include config=webutil_webstart (or whichever one is most appropriate for your use-case.

I think I'm not following... are you talking about some options that I can run client side? I did recompile my local webutil.pll as you mention, but it didn't seem to change anything. I do develop on Oracle Forms, but can't do any changes on the server side of things other than on specific forms, which I don't think are the problem here.
I too tried to log into the application by changing the URL to this: http://forms2xxx-yyy.zzz.es/forms/frmservlet?config=webutil_webstart, this prompted the download of a file (frmservlet.jnlp) but otherwise it run as usual, I haven't noticed any changes.

What do you mean "it ran as usual"?  Does that mean the app worked as you expected?  And yes, if you use the webstart configuration(s) you will be prompted to save the jnlp file, which you then need to run (double-click) on to start the app.

No, with "ran as usual" I meant it loaded the Forms Servlet and the webapp but nothing changed, I still get the same "FileFunction bean not found" error when trying to load a document. I double click on that jnpl file but it doesn't seem to do anything, I get a JAVA loading screen for a second but nothing else happens.
